# Show shadow for SCNScene from .dae file [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've got a **SCNView** with a **SCNScene** from a .dae file. I can access the objects in the scene, move and modify them properly, but I don't find the way to show the shadow projected by the light over the object.

```
SCNView *myScene.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"scene.dae"];
```

The scene already includes lights and shadows, I can preview them, but the SCNView only shows the lights, not the projected shadow.

Do you know how to make the shadow visible? I know **SpriteKit** allows it, but I need to use **SceneKit** for my 3D scene.

Many thanks